# How to Get Report Universe Path via BO API? universe path display null

Tags: path, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I wanna get report universe via api, steps as described below

1. Open report document
2. `DataProvider dp = dps.getItem(i);  //get report data providers`
3. `DataSource ds = dp.getDataSource(); //get data source`
4. `universe.setFilePath(ds.getDomainName() + "/"+dp.getSource()+".unv"); //get datasource -- universe domain/path`

mostly, I got correct data like this `/DEV_folder/testUNV.unv`

seldomly, the result is `null/testUNV.unv` or `\DEV_folder\testUNV.unv`

any idea why?

Business Objects server version is Enterprise XI 3.1 SP7, using java SDK

---

Thank you **Joe**.
But this may not solve my problem, you provide 3 possibilities, see my comments below

- *The universe is not in a folder* — No, reports using the same universe, one can get path, the other one cannot
- *The universe is in a folder that you don't have access to (although you have access to the universe)* — No, reports using same universe, which I have read and write privilege.
- *The data source is not a universe* — it is a universe.

Sorry I cannot provide screenshot due to lack of reputations.

> **Contract - 4th Party Supplier Consent Form Report**
>
> /eSourcing_Dev/Contract.unv
>
> /eSourcing_Dev/Project Save.unv
>
> **Contract 4th Party Supplier Consent Form Report**
>
> null/Contract.unv
>
> null/Project Save.unv

Contract - 4th Party Supplier Consent Form Report and Contract 4th Party Supplier Consent Form Report connect to the same universes, Contract.unv and Project Save.unv, but the path display null.

If I open Contract 4th Party Supplier Consent Form Report on BO Infoview and just save the report again, then I can get the correct path.

> **Report Name**
>
> Project ? Milestones
>
> **Universe**
>
> /eSourcing/Project Save.unv
>
> \eSourcing/Project Save.unv

Project ? Milestones report get 2 different path

```
/eSourcing/Project Save.unv

\eSourcing/Project Save.unv
```

they should be one report, 2 query(2 data provider), using the same universe.

I already provided actual code/API I used, loop omitted. Please check the steps I described.
What I am trying to do is get all the reports and their universe in a batch.

Comment: It would help if you'd indicate what version of BusinessObjects you're using and which API (.NET, COM, …).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at the API documentation of the [Report Engine API](http://help.sap.com/javadocs/boe/xi31/re/en/index.html) and couldn't really determine what the `getDomainName()` call is supposed to return. *Domains* where a notion that was used in pre-XI releases; AFAIK this concept no longer exists in the XI versions.

If you want to get the path of the universe, I do the following:

1. Get the datasource ID, using `getID()` method of the `DataSource` interface.
2. Retrieve the `InfoObject` (using the [BusinessObjects Enterprise API](http://help.sap.com/javadocs/boe/xi31/boe/en/index.html)) using the ID from step 1.
3. Retrieve the parent ID for the universe, using the `getParentID()` method of the `IInfoObject` interface, check that this is a folder object and cast to an `IFolder` interface.
4. Use the `getPath()` method of the `IFolder` interface to return the full path.

Keep in mind that sometimes a Webi report will report that it's not linked to any universe, so-called unbound reports. See [this blog post](http://www.businessobjectstips.com/tips/web-intelligence/what-is-an-unbound-report-and-why-should-i-care/) for more information about this issue.

Comment: Hi Kristof, thx! furthermore, do u know how to get dataSource cuid directly? As dataSource.getID() method returns a long string like this "DS0.UnivCUID=M08xU2AACvD_AhcA4gAAQkUAAqmtID0AAAA;UnivID=339394;ShortName=Project Save;UnivName=Project Save", substr is required.

Comment: If you're just interested in the universes used by the Webi document, you could also use the `getUniverses()` of the IWebi interface. This will give you a Set of universe IDs. This way, you don't need to look at the individual data providers or user the Report Engine API.

Comment: what I am trying to do is get all the universes which a report links to and look at theirs path.

Comment: As I said, in that case you don't need the Report Engine API. Just use the BusinessObjects Enterprise API; you should be able to retrieve all the information you need with the `IInfoObject`, `IWebi` and `IFolder` interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons for the "null":

- The universe is not in a folder.
- The universe is in a folder that you don't have access to (although you have access to the universe)
- The data source is not a universe

Try printing out the result of ds.getUniverseID() and then run a CMS query on that ID.  That may give you more insight as to the problem.

I can't explain the "\".  If you could provide more of your code and the **actual** results that you get, I may be able to help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
But this may not solve my problem, you provide 3 possibilities, see my comments below
• The universe is not in a folder.       //No, reports using the same universe, one can get path, the other one cannot
• The universe is in a folder that you don't have access to (although you have access to the universe)       //No, reports using same universe, which I have read and write privilege.
• The data source is not a universe      //   it is a universe.
Let me insert some screen shot into the question

Comment: I haven't solved your problem, but I've narrowed it a bit. From my testing, *sometimes* the universe domain is prefixed with "\" and sometimes not. I haven't yet found a pattern. For the reports that are showing "null", were they migrated from an older version of BO?

Comment: Yes, don't know when "\" will happen. I am wondering if I use the wrong API method, but I failed to find another one.   regrading "null", we upgraded BO server to SP7, but only 1/30 reports have "null" issue. I guessed it is caused by exporting from web intelligence, but I tried this case, I can get the correct path.